# Tensorflow [Errno 2] - not creating "/svg/summary-icon.svg" so cannot visualize in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I get "WARNING:root:Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/.../svg/summary-icon.svg' (The svg part of the path is missing in my file system) when trying to generate a TensorFlow graph to then look at in TensorBoard. I suspect this is a known bug and wonder of rebuilding TensorFlow with Bazel is the way to go? I am not a software engineer so hope there is an easier way to get the graph to show inside TensorBoard. Any help will be gratefully welcomed.

Comment: Sorry, should have also stated I used pip to install tensorflow version 0.5.0

Comment: That is an extremely old release (relative to TensorFlow's lifetime), so I'm not too surprised that something's broken. You don't need to build from source: the [pip packages](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation) are quite up to date.

Comment: Thanks Allen, the dangers in following books (;-). I will upgrade to the latest version. Many thanks. Roy